# Process a file list with space in file names

Tags: bash, shell-script, whitespace

I am trying develop a bash script which processes a list of files which may contain space names.

(I have already consulted [Trouble in script with spaces in filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57830/trouble-in-script-with-spaces-in-filename) and [Why I can't escape spaces on a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108635/why-i-cant-escape-spaces-on-a-bash-script), but can not seem to perfect my script.)

Here is my script. The actual process is more complicated which I reduce here to simple `file` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Usage is $0 <files to be tested>"
   exit
fi

allfilestobetesed=$@
for filetobetested in "$allfilestobetested"
do
    file "$filetobetested"
done
```

How do I improve my script?

Comment: Are the names with spaces being quoted when invoking the script?

Comment: @EricRenouf No. This is mostly `*` or `*.tex` or something similar.

Comment: The shell will expand them correctly there, so that should be OK I think.

Comment: @Masroor you made a mistake in copying what was posted. Use `"@"` not `'"$@"'` Also it is generally more helpful to put the `set -x` inside the script.

Comment: @rocky I thought that at first too, but that's just how `set -x` ends up displaying the `"$@"` part, I tried it locally and saw the same thing, it just turned out to be a typo further down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably get rid of your `allfilestobetested` variable if you can:

```
for filetobetested in "$@"; do
    file "$filetobetested"
done
```

will expand correctly

Comment: Funny, this won't work if you run it like this: `bash a.sh $(ls -1)` (supposing that you save this script as `a.sh`).

Comment: @Kira Right, because then you're getting a string as output from `ls -1` and using that string as the arguments to `a.sh`, which will be subject to word splitting rules.  Basically meaning all the spaces will be processed before you start running `a.sh`.  That means you can't do much to fix it from within

Comment: But does is strip out the '\n' too? I've tried splitting the output in the loop by line breaks with `IFS=$'\n'`, but with no success =/

Comment: @kira I fear you've set for yourself a very difficult task if you want to try to use `ls` there.  You might want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a good discussion of why it's going to be very difficult to get it to do what you want.  Also, as I noted, if you are setting `IFS` inside your script that's too late, since bash is doing the word splitting to assign the output of `ls` to the arguments to the script before the script is invoked.  It's too late when you're inside a.sh, the damage is already done so to speak

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close. First, you got right using $@ instead of $*.

You need to worry about shell expansion so don't use `"` unnecessarily as happened in the assignment. That will remove the boundaries between tokens. However you *do* need it around "@_".

So we have:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Usage is $0 <files to be tested>"
   exit
fi

for filetobetested in "$@"
do
    file "$filetobetested"
done
```

Lastly, my bash debugger http://bashdb.sf.net can help you follow stuff like this. [Section 1.2 of the bashdb manual](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashdb.html#Interactive-Line-Tracing-Session) describes how to set PS4 to give more information from `set -x` tracing.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this answer differ from the other answer already posted?

Comment: I started writing it it at the same time as the first answer. It took me longer to write though because I was explaining _why_ the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `"$@"`:

```
    for filetobetested
    do
        file "$filetobetested"
    done
```

Comment: Yes, I do. The `file` command is not the actual command in the real script, where the files need to be processed individually.

Comment: No you don't.  My statement has nothing to do with whether you use the `file` command or not.  `for xyz in "$@"` means exactly the same thing as `for xyz` with no `in` clause.  From the dash (posix shell) manpage:  _Omitting `in word` ... is equivalent to `in "$@"`_.  The bash shell works the same way.